# What files are pulled in by update-initramfs?

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, initrd

I need to know what config and data files are pulled in to make the `initrd.img-xxx` when update-initramfs (mkinitramfs) is executed.

I am having a video driver problem that I have narrowed down to the generation of the `initrd.img-xxx` after kernel updates. I only get low-resolution single screen VESA, I should have two screen 1080p.

Debian 12 Bookworm, but it's an old install that has been upgraded from earlier versions of Debian. I still have a working fallback kernel from 2 months ago, so I set it as manually installed and held back from upgrades for now.

I created a fresh installation of Debian on a spare drive with its own EFI boot sector and grub and it has no issues. I have, as best as I can query, the same graphics drivers and firmware installed in both installs, and I purged all of them from the old install and reinstalled with apt to get fresh configs if any. I also purged and reinstalled the kernel metapackage and initram tools.

I have two identical kernel builds installed in both the old and new installs. I copied the `initrd.img-123` from the new install to the old install. The old install boots correctly with correct graphics using the `initrd.img-123` from the new install.

The initrd.img of the new and old install are of different file type when listed by `file initrd.img-XXX` and they don't unpack the same when attempting to decompress. The new is making zstd files and the old system are appearing as CPIO. (The older fallback kernel also appears to have a CPIO initrd.img but doesn't have problems.)

I have mounted both root partitions and done `diff -r` on /boot and /etc and cleaned up the most obvious differences with apt-get purging old packages and some manual house keeping. But there is still a lot of noise due to heirloom configurations and settings, much of which I would like to keep if this doesn't drag on too long.

Comment: For anyone wondering. Purging package amd64-microcode fixed the issue with the initrd file format, it was blacklisted by default anyway so I don't know what the real issue with it was.(Lots of cobwebs in a 5 year old desktop OS.) And the graphics issue was solved in `/etc/modprobe.d/` somehow `amdgpu` had become blacklisted, commented out and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `update-initramfs` with a "verbose" option, e.g. `update-initramfs -u -v`, it will display the name of every file it adds to the initramfs, and every hook script it executes.

Comment: `update-initramfs -u -v > initdumpOSa` followed by `sort` then `comm -1 -3 initdumpOSa.sorted initdumpOSb.sorted` really helped me narrow down the suspects. `lsinitramfs` is a bit simpler but only lists included files, dumping the `update-initramfs` also shows hooks used in building it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`lsinitramfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initramfs-tools-core/lsinitramfs.8) to list the contents of an initramfs and thus compare the working and non-working files you have.

The contents are mostly determined by [`/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs.conf.5), in particular the `MODULES` value.

Comment: lsinitramfs seems to be a component of dracut not Debian's initramfs-tools, and not availible as its own package.

Comment: All files under `/etc/initramfs-tools/` are identical. Mysteries.

Comment: The link I gave for `lsinitramfs` is to the *Debian* manpage for the tool, so yes, it is available in Debian. It’s [part of the `initramfs-tools-core` package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/all/initramfs-tools-core/filelist) and is installed in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I purged and reinstalled initramfs-tools along with a bunch of other stuff and yeah lsinitramfs is in there now.